# Expressjs Incorrect Redirect after POST method

Tags: javascript, express, url-routing

I have a form page that is routed to /admin/posts/create. When the form is submitted, there should be a POST method with a redirect to '/'. The issue is that when I submit the form, the redirect is not allowing for the post to go through. `Cannot POST /`. What is preventing this from happening?

routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');

//index 
router.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));

    router.route('/') 


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res, next) {

            Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {




                if (err) return next(err)

                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);


                        blogpost.title = req.body.title; // get the blog title
                        blogpost.author = req.body.author; // get the author name
                        blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // get tagline
                        blogpost.content = req.body.content; // get the blog content
                        blogpost.category = req.body.category; // get the category
                        blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // get the tags


                        res.format({
                            html: function() {
                                res.render('pages/index', {
                                    blogpost: blogpost,
                                    pageCount: pageCount,
                                    itemCount: itemCount
                                })
                            },
                            json: function() {

                                res.json({
                                    object: 'blogpost',
                                    has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                    data: blogpost
                                })
                            }
                        }); // END res.format(html, json)
            }); // END Blogpost.paginate
        }); // END GET method

router.route('/admin/posts/create')

    // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                });

        }) // END POST method


        .get(function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/blogpost-create');
        });
```

blogpost-create.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.5/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid grid-pad">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <h1>Blog Create</h1>


            <form action="/" method="POST">
                Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
                Author: 
                    <select>
                        <option>Author</option>
                    </select><br>
                Category: 
                    <select>
                        <option>Analytics/SEO/SEM</option>
                        <option>Advice</option>
                        <option>Programming</option>
                        <option>Thoughts</option>
                    </select><br>
                Tagline: <input type="text" maxlength:"160" name="tagline"><br>
                Content:<br>
                <textarea name="blog-editor" id="blog-editor" rows="10" cols="80">
                    Text editor.
                </textarea><br>
                Tags: <input type="text" name="tags"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="blog-editor"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'blog-editor' );
    </script>

    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no route `POST /`, only a route `GET /`.

Add

```
.post(function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({test: 'Hello World!'});
})
```

after `router.route('/')` and try again.